# AutoCompleteTextView dropdown not showing after device rotation

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I have the following AutoCompleteTextView:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/offering_type_dropdown_layout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/date_card_spacing"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/offering_details_header_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/offering_details_date_layout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:hint="@string/offering_type_hint">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/offering_details_type_dropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

In my Activity's `onCreate`, I fill the AutoCompleteTextView like this:

```
    String[] TYPES = new String[] {getString(R.string.burnt_offering), getString(R.string.meal_offering), getString(R.string.peace_offering), getString(R.string.sin_offering)};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(OfferingInputActivity.this, R.layout.offering_types_dropdown, TYPES);
    mOfferingTypeCombo.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then I populate the view using a Room database and preselect one of the values. In the Room callback, I do:

```
  mOfferingTypeCombo.setText(getString(R.string.meal_offering)), false);
```

Everything works well on the initial run, and the dropdown is shown correctly:

[image]

**Now I rotate the device to landscape.** The very same code as above is executed **but this time, the dropdown box only shows the current selection**:

[image]

For some reason, all other entries in the adapter have disappeared. I have tried hacks such as `setAdapter(null)` before I set the adapter, but no success. **Can someone tell me why after rotation, the dropdown is missing entries even though the exact same code is executed?**

Comment: There is a bug about it: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1464

Comment: Thanks, you are right. My workaround is in the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there is a open bug on [this topic](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1464).

You can use as workaround the **`setFreezesText`** method:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView =
    view.findViewById(R.id.offering_details_type_dropdown);
autoCompleteTextView.setFreezesText(false);
```

The `EditText` set the `freezesText=true`. Due to this value after the rotation the `TextView#onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable)` calls [`autoCompleteTextView.setText(value,true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20boolean)) which applies a filter to the adapter values.

Comment: This doesnt work for me, creating class which inherit autoCompleteTextView and overwriting its getFreezeText method as suggested by phillips77 here https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1464 works for me

Answer (score 5):

This custom `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`
resolves all problems:

```
class ExposedDropdownMenu : MaterialAutoCompleteTextView {

constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr
)

override fun getFreezesText(): Boolean {
    return false
}

init {
    inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable? {
    val parcelable = super.onSaveInstanceState()
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        return parcelable
    }
    val customSavedState = CustomSavedState(parcelable)
    customSavedState.text = text.toString()
    return customSavedState
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?) {
    if (state !is CustomSavedState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
        return
    }
    setText(state.text, false)
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state.superState)
}

private class CustomSavedState(superState: Parcelable?) : BaseSavedState(superState) {
    var text: String? = null

    override fun writeToParcel(out: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags)
        out.writeString(text)
    }
}
}
```

**[Source](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1464#issuecomment-703849555)**

**Note:** It may not works correctly in older APIs like 23 or below.
one way is using a custom `ArrayAdapter` that prevents to **Filter** texts.

```
class NoFilterArrayAdapter : ArrayAdapter<Any?> {

constructor(context: Context, resource: Int) : super(context, resource)
constructor(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: Array<out Any?>) : super(context, resource, objects)

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults? {
            return null
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {}
       }
   }
}
```

usage:

```
val adapter = NoFilterArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
```

Comment: Saved me a ton of time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue when orientation changes add this in XML

android:saveEnabled="false"

Answer (score 0):

Like @Gabriele Mariotti mentioned, it's a bug. As mentioned in the posted link, I did this workaround which works well:

```
public class ExposedDropDown extends MaterialAutoCompleteTextView {
       public ExposedDropDown(@NonNull final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attributeSet) {
          super(context, attributeSet);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean getFreezesText() {
         return false;
       }
}
```

Comment: yes it is works but text of item remove after rotation.

Answer (score 0):

1. I solved this by deleting id from AutoCompleteTextView. This id is responsible for saving text after rotating.
2. Save string from AutoCompleteTextView in onSaveInstanceState method.

Code:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputAddress"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/Address">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"
/>
```

fragment.class

```
class CashierAddFragment : Fragment() {

var mBinding: FragmentCashierAddBinding? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val binding = FragmentCashierAddBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        initAddressSpinner(binding, "")
    } else {
        initAddressSpinner(binding, savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_ADDRESS))
    }

    mBinding = binding

    return binding.root
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    val address = mBinding!!.inputAddress.getTrimText()
    outState.putString(KEY_ADDRESS, address)

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}

private fun initAddressSpinner(binding: FragmentCashierAddBinding, initValue: String?) {
    val items = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4")
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.list_item, items)

    val autoTxtAddress = binding.inputAddress.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView
    autoTxtAddress?.setText(initValue)
    autoTxtAddress?.setAdapter(adapter)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by @Mohsents worked for me. This is the java version of his code that I used:

```
public class NoFilterArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

public NoFilterArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

public NoFilterArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, Object[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        }
    };
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This fix on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1464#issuecomment-1258051448) seems to work:

```
autoCompleteTextView.isSaveEnabled = false
```